# How can I remove an attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I can't seem to get `removeAttr` to work, I'm using the example I saw on the jQuery site. Basically `onclick` I add the attribute to disable a field (which works just fine) but when the user clicks again it should enable the field in question. I used alerts to make sure the else block is being fired, so I know that's not it.

Code:

```
$('#WindowOpen').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#forgot_pw').slideToggle(600);

  if('#forgot_pw') {
    $('#login_uname, #login_pass').attr('disabled','disabled');
  } else {
    $('#login_uname, #login_pass').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: if('#forgot_pw') will always run. I'm guessing this is a typo?

Comment: For future reference, jQuery recommends using the `.prop()` method (http://api.jquery.com/prop/) when getting and setting input properties like disabled. It's more cross browser friendly depending on the version of jQuery you use and what browser your users navigate with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove disabled attribute using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All good used this:

```
$('#WindowOpen').toggle(
    function()
    {
        $('#login_uname, #login_pass').attr("disabled","disabled");     
    },
    function()
    {
        $('#login_uname, #login_pass').removeAttr("disabled");      
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that the following line of code will always evaluate to true.

```
if('#forgot_pw')
```

try replacing with

```
if($('#forgot_pw').attr('disabled'))
```

Comment: Same problem, I get it to disable but not re-enable.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#forgot_pw').attr('disabled', false);
```

should work for you.