# IE7 & 8 add unwanted drop shadow to a table inside of another table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the follwing jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PrkUW/

There you will find a list-table which has a drop shadow filter applied to it. Inside one of it's rows I have another table, inner-table, which doesn't have any drop shadow declared on it. The problem is that both IE7 and 8 add drop shadow to the inner-table and to it's parent row, and I can't remove it using JS or CSS.

I've tried $('.inner-table').css('filter', '') too but can't get it to work. And as you can see on IE7 the inner-table column's width are a total mess, and borders appear without any declaration.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to make it look right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can u check with

```
$('.inner-table').css('filter', null)
```

or

using

```
.removeAttr('class');
```

[jQuery remove attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785071/jquery-remove-attribute)

Comment: css('filter', null) not working. removing the class attribute from the inner-table destroys it and the text inside it gets the drop shadow.