# Disable and Enable submit button in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, yii

I am using jquery to disable the submit button and load loading image,

In submit button I am using the folowing :

```
<div id="registerbtn" name="registerbtn">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" icon="ok white" value="Register" id="register" name="register"/>
</div>
<div class="span4" style="display:none;" id="loadingtext">
                            <?php echo  $imghtml=CHtml::image('images/loading.gif');?>                      
                        </div>
```

and in JQuery, I am using following code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#register').click(function() {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');

     });
        $("#loadingtext").show();
    });
});
```

When I do this, then this button is disabled permanently, but if I want to remove then what should I do ??

Comment: can you specify when you want to enable submit button

Comment: I am using yii to submit this form, when this form is submitted then it is validated, at this time i want to disable this button, if there are errors then I want to enable otherwise, proceed to next view

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785071/jquery-remove-attribute
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button?rq=1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method and use the `$(this)` to reference the target  element within the callback function

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  const $register = $("#register"),
        $loading = $("#loading");

  $register.on("click", function() {
  
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $loading.show();
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      $register.prop('disabled', false);
      $loading.hide();
    }, 2000);

  });

});
```

```html
<input id="register" value="Register" type="submit">
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">Wait 2 sec...</div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: @lord_linus it's not exactly the way you need it but there are all the tips you need! thx! happy coding

Comment: one more problem, I am getting that by using this, I am not able to submit the data,

Comment: @lord_linus sorry was away, you fixed that issue?

Comment: ,I just fixed the issue but not in the proper way, it was just for work , this is my script`
$('#register').click(function() {
$("#registerbtn").hide();
$("#loadingtext").show();
});`and this is my div `<div id="registerbtn">
<input type="submit" value="Send Instruction" id="register" name="register"/>
</div>
<div class="form-actions" style="display:none;" id="loadingtext">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" icon="ok white" value="Send Instruction" id="register"  disabled="disabled"/><?php echo  $imghtml=CHtml::image('images/loading.gif');?>      </div>`

Answer (score 10):

This is answered in the [jQuery FAQ](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/)

> **How do I disable/enable a form element?**
>   There are two ways to disable/enable form elements.

Set the 'disabled' attribute to true or false:

```
 // Disable #x
 $('#x').attr('disabled', true);
 // Enable #x
 $('#x').attr('disabled', false);
```

Add or remove the 'disabled' attribute:

```
 // Disable #x
 $("#x").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 // Enable #x
 $("#x").removeAttr('disabled');
```

**Update:** Now the way to do it (as said by FAQ) is only:

```
// Disable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", true );

// Enable #x
$( "#x" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```

Answer (score 0):

To permanently remove the button

```
$('#register').remove();
```

To restore the button

```
$('#register').attr('disabled',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `$('#divID').remove();` what you're looking for?

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove

Comment: actually I want to enable the button again if I am getting any error in the registration

Answer (score 0):

### Enable disabled properties

```
 $('#apply-coupon').removeAttr('Disabled');
```

### Disable disabled properties

```
$('#apply-coupon').attr('disabled', 'disabled' );
```