# Ajax and switch

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with this.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function edit(str){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
document.getElementById("editdialog").innerHTML=conection.responseText;                
$( "#editdialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 425
                });
              }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","edit.php?id="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>

$query=mysql_result(SELECT * FROM paises)

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      echo $row['pais'];
      echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"edit('".$row["ICAO"]."')\">Edit</a>";
}

?>
<div id="editdialog" title="Edit"></div>
```

and the edit.php file:

```
    <script src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.effect.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#editaircraft")
            .button()
            .click(function(event) {
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
require_once ('config.php');
$icao = $_REQUEST["icao"];

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Number Classes:</td><td><select id="numberclasses" name="numberclasses">';
        echo "<option value='0'>Select Number of Classes</option>";
        echo "<option value='1'>One Classes (Economy)</option>";
        echo "<option value='2'>Two Classes (Business & Economy)</option>";
        echo "<option value='3'>Three Classes (First, Business & Economy)</option>";
echo '</select></td></tr>';



echo '<tr><td class="forms">First Class Seats:</td><td><input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="firstclassseats" name="firstclassseats" size="30" value=';
echo $row["FirstClassSeats"] . "></td></tr>";


echo '<tr><td class="forms">Business Class Seats:</td><td><input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="businessclassseats" name="businessclassseats" size="30" value=';
echo $row["BusinessClassSeats"] . "></td></tr>";

echo '<tr><td class="forms">Economy Class Seats:</td><td><input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="economyclassseats" name="economyclassseats" size="30" value=';
echo $row["EconomyClassSeats"] . "></td></tr>";

?>

<script>

$("#numberclasses").change(function() {
value = $(this).val();

str = parseInt(value);

switch(str)
  {
    case 0:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#businessclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#economyclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
    break;

    case 1:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#businessclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
    break;

     case 2:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#businessclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
    break;

    case 3:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#firstclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#businessclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
});
    break;

  }
});

</script>

<?php

echo "<tr><td><input id='editaircraft' type='submit' value='Edit Aircraft'></td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>

</form>
```

The problem is this script:

```
$("#numberclasses").change(function() {
value = $(this).val();

str = parseInt(value);

switch(str)
  {
    case 0:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#businessclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#economyclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
    break;

    case 1:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#businessclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
    break;

     case 2:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#businessclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
    break;

    case 3:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#firstclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#businessclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
});
    break;

  }
});

</script>
```

This script must activate and deactivate in function the selection of the select. But if I do this in the file all works perfect. But If I want to do it by the index.php with the Edit link Ajax opens the dialog but the script don´t work. I select the option but the inputs not change.

Comment: where is the change handler code located? file and location of code in that file. Important since `ready` event has occurred in main page when AJAX loaded code is run

Comment: that doesn't answer question

Comment: would help if you answer question about which file and where within the file the change handler code is

Comment: The files are in the same directory. And you can see the GET with the file in the question post.

Comment: OK so `$("#numberclasses").change`  is in `edit.php` and is placed after all the html?

Comment: Yes!!! It is in the edit.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#numberclasses").change(function() {
value = $(this).val();

str = parseInt(value);

switch(str)
  {
    case 0:

        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#businessclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#economyclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");

    break;

    case 1:

        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#businessclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");

    break;

     case 2:

        $("#businessclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#firstclassseats").attr("disabled","disabled");

    break;

    case 3:

        $("#firstclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#businessclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#economyclassseats").removeAttr('disabled');

    break;

  }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Try this $('#firstclassseats').attr('disabled', true);

Comment: Do you get any value to str ? please comment the switch statement and alert(str).

Comment: No, but in the file yes. If I use it in the index.php no!

Comment: Are you using XMLHttpRequest in the file which is working for you? if you dont use XMLHttpRequest in the file i think the problem is because of XMLHttpRequest try to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Also i can see there is a another post regarding this issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785071/jquery-remove-attribute

Comment: I use which it is in the example on the index.php on the question post.