# How can I remove On click attribute using "nav-item dropdown" class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I remove On click attribute using "nav-item dropdown" class

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">                    
<a class="nav-link " "="" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="window.location.href='/camping-tents'">Camping Tents</a></li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">                    
<a class="nav-link " "="" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="window.location.href='/camping-tents2'">Camping 3</a></li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">                    
<a class="nav-link " "="" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="window.location.href='/camping-tents3'">Camping 3</a></li>

<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " bell-tents" style="background:0;"> Bell Tents</a></li>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. What have you tried? Does this answer your question? [How can I remove an attribute with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785071/jquery-remove-attribute)

Comment: Your HTML has extra characters. Is that what it actually looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all links under elements that have "nav-item dropdown" class and then itirate over these `a` elements to remove their `onclick` attributes:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item.dropdown a')).forEach((el) => {
  el.removeAttribute('onclick')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your markup issues. Then, use `.removeAttribute('onclick')` method on the elements in question.